# ssh key suddenly denied

Tags: ssh, permissions, digital-ocean

I had trouble with ssh at first, and a lot of the answers here and in other communities were really helpful, so first of all thank you :). Secondly, I suddenly started having this issue where my ssh key is getting the Permission denied (publickey) error again, however nothing has changed since when it was working... [I've attached a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjOp5.png). Does anyone know what the reason might possibly be??

Thank you!

Comment: This is a pretty common question. There are half a dozen things that could cause this. You should check the syslogs on the server to see if sshd is logging a reason why it's rejecting you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is within your sshd_config file.

Log as root to you server

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config or nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Change the value next to PasswordAuthentication from no to yes.

Then reload the service

```
sudo service sshd reload
```

With this done, you can now set up your new SSH key for your LOCAL device.
To do this, you can run the following from your LOCAL device, not the server:

```
ssh-copy-id username@ip
```